# URL Rewrite infinite redirects problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I have the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ /blah.php?g=$1
```

I'm trying to make a url such as

```
example.com/f/three
```

to be interpreted as

```
example.com/blah.php?g=three.
```

However, visiting a url like the former results in a "maximum internal redirects" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you go directly to /blah.php?g=three ?

Comment: it works as it should, with no redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was an additional sneaky .htaccess file inside a folder with the same name as f, which was causing all the redirects. Here is what ended up being the correct line:

```
RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ /blah.php?g=$1
```

Since this is in a .htaccess file, the slash before the f should be absent.

Comment: Ahh, I'm glad you found the answer, and answered your own question.  :)